# Excel find top 10 values on each column

Tags: excel, office365, excel-2010, multiple-columns, top-n

Let's say I have a table: the columns correspond to years (such as 1999, 2000, ..., 2020) and the rows are countries.

How can I make Excel display only the top 10 values of each column and set other countries values =0 ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume the first cell ("Country") is the cell **`A1`**.

1. Open your sheet.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
3. Insert => Module
4. Paste this code:

```vb
Sub leave_top_10_on_every_column()
  Dim iLastRow As Long
  Dim iLastCol As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim dblTop10 As Double

  iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
  iLastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

  For i = 2 To iLastCol
    dblTop10 = WorksheetFunction.Large(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn, 10)
    For j = 2 To iLastRow
      If ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i) < dblTop10 Then ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i) = 0
    Next
  Next

End Sub
```

5. Put the mouse pointer somewhere in the middle of this code and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the code.

Comment: thank you for your answer!and finally i turn to use python's pandas to deal with this problem